# How do I wildcard a string when I'm asserting a method is called with it? Python3 mock

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking, wildcard, assert

When using `mock`'s `call()` objects with `assert_has_calls`, I'm struggling to assert a given string has been used with an unknown value appended to the end.

For example:

**Code under test:**

```
mystring = 'a known string with an unknown value: {0}'.format(unknown_value)
method_to_call(mystring)
```

**Current test code:**

```
with mock.patch('method_to_call') as mocked_method:
  calls = [call('a known string with and unknown value: {0}'.format(mock.ANY)]
  call_method()
  mocked_method.assert_has_calls(calls)
```

This gives me something along the lines of:

```
AssertionError: Calls not found.
Expected: [call('a known string with and unknown value: <ANY>')]
```

How can I assert that the given string has been passed to the method but allow for the unknown value?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the [`callee`](https://github.com/Xion/callee) lib to do partial matching on the string that is used in the method call:

```py
from callee import String, Regex

with mock.patch('method_to_call') as mocked_method:
    call_method()
    mocked_method.assert_called_with(String() & Regex('a known string with an unknown value: .*'))
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to add another lib and you're sure that you know the order of the calls, you can extract the string from the call args and then match using regex

```py
import re

with mock.patch('method_to_call') as mocked_method:
  call_method()
  argument_string = mocked_method.call_args[0][0]

  pattern = re.compile("a known string with an unknown value: .*")
  assert pattern.match(argument_string)
```

Comment: Awesome shout for using `callee` that's a very nice library! I used Regex in the end from it.

Comment: Ah! Good point if that matches your use case better - I'll edit the answer

Answer (score 0):

An slightly tweaked alternative to what user3623641 suggested without using an extra library could be the following:

```py
with mock.patch('method_to_call') as mocked_method:
  call_method()
  argument_string = mocked_method.call_args[0][0]
  assert "a known string with and unknown value:" in argument_string
```

This way the code just checks if your given string `"a known string with and unknown value:"` is present in the string that is used in the method call.